# how to identify an impulse response in a system?

Tags: system

Now I'm trying to identify the impulse response in a system.
Basically,  as I know,  there are consisted with impulse response and gaussian response in a system.

But I don't know how to identify the impulse response. 
Would you let me know how to identify the impulse response ina system?
Even if some hints please.

Comment: Get a hammer and a chart recorder?   In all seriousness, that would depend on what sort of system - do you want to do this analytically or are you trying to measure something?

Comment: @ChrisStratton No joke- we have a calibrated and instrumented hammer. Like [this one](http://www.bksv.com/Products/transducers/vibration/impact-hammers/8206?tab=specifications)

Answer (score 1):

If you are speaking about a real system, i would suggest making an impulse and measuring response. Also it would be easier (for most cases) to measure frequency response- by sweeping sine waves through the whole spectrum of interest and measuring the output. Then just calculate the pulse response.

By the way, this is a nice feature in control systems.

Comment: Is this able to identify to just calculate the pulse response? How to mesure and determine?

Comment: You measure the frequency response, then you can calculate anything. The rest depends on the system.

Comment: Thanks can you let me know do you have any recommend  example  ?

Comment: or any hint or article also good for me,

Comment: Again, i first need to know, what is your system

Comment: oh sorry, my system is a FPGA board with speaker and microphone. the FPGA's input is from ADC output of a microphone

Comment: Ok. In acoustic system it's going to be a nightmare. You need calibrated equipment for your frequency range. It's expensive. But the idea is exactly the same: output 60dBA on each frequency between 10Hz to 10kHz (or whatever range you need) with steps of 10 points per decade, and the measure the output same way. The expensive equipment is required to be sure you really output what you think. Unlike motion systems, in acoustic the measurement really affects the result, so you need ti choose well known sensor.

Answer (score 1):

If your trying to find the [transfer function](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Transfer_Functions) of a physical system, then you need system identification theory. In short there is an input \$ x(t)\$ and an output \$ y(t)\$ and the idea is to find a frequency model \$ H(s) \$ to find out what the "black box" is doing to the input.

[image: Wiki: Transfer Function]

The general idea is that you have to excite all frequencies to come up with a good model. This can be done with a frequency sweep (chirp signal), an [impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_response), or noise (like white noise which is noise across all frequencies).

If you are trying to do this physically, certain methods work better than others. Airplane and satellite frames are physically hit with a hammer (input) and then monitored with accelerators (output). Motors are best characterized with a frequency sweep to find the transfer function. To find a low pass filter pole, random noise can be injected and then an fft can find the frequency cutoff.

If you are doing for academics sakes, its all math. The transfer function will be given. Just plug in.

\$ x(t) = \delta(t) \$

\$Y(s) = H(s)*\mathcal{L}\{\delta(t)\} \$

Comment: Thanks Good answer, BTW can you let me know a little more easily? I'm not doing with academics just want to know practically in the fields

Comment: Oh, this smelled like a homework problem. Thats why I included both. However, you really need to understand lapalace if you want to understand transfer functions.

Comment: No,  this is not a homework. As I know, the impulse signal is a very short strong magnitude. so I can't imagine what if I put the impulse signal into a system. how can I identify. Also the reason of like this dummy question is i'm not familiar with math.

Comment: A dirac delta function has infinite amplitude at DC (if that makes any sense.) If you added up every sine wave across all frequencies (from DC to frequencies that aren't physically possible), you would get a dirac delta function. Thats the maths part. The unmaths part is snapping your fingers, you will have a broad spectrum of frequencies summed up at one point in time. If you happened to snap your fingers next to a tuning fork, it would ring. But none of this makes sense if you don't understand how things translate from the time domain to the frequency domain, it just won't.

Comment: Did you mean that we can find the impulse signal after transferring time domain to frequency domain? I know what if I use DCT(Discrete cosine transform or FFT) then can extract the frequency information from time domain. BTW what is the relationship between DC,AC and impulse signal)? did you mean that the dc imply impulse signal?

Comment: I think that you want to say " convolution".

Answer (score 0):

A good way of identifying the system is to inject a PRBS (pseudo random binary signal) sequence into a system and record the response. The PRBS is used because the autocorrelation of PRBS gives a neat peak signal at time zero, in other words with the use of correlation between input excitation PRBS signal and output system you are able to get impulse response.
1. Inject PRBS
2. Record system response (t)
3. Corellation PRBS vs Sytem response
4. DFT
Then you get system impulse response

Comment: Is this the same as Laplace inversion conversion ?